# If U and W are subspaces of the vector space V, show that (U+W)/W ≅ U/(U ∩ W)?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Im having trouble with this question:

If U and W are subspaces of the vector space V, show that (U+W)/W ≅ U/(U ∩ W)?

So I know I have to show that there is an isomorphism from (U+W)/W to U/(U ∩ W). To do so I'd assume I would have to show that ø((U+W/W))->U/(U ∩ W) is injective and surjective. So, the ker ø = 0 to show that it is injective. And ø((U+W/W)) = U/(U ∩ W) to show that it is surjective.

If I'm not mistaken (U+W)/W is the set of cosets of W and elements of (U+W)/W would look like W+(u+w) and U/(U ∩ W) is the set of cosets of (U ∩ W) with elements that look like (U ∩ W)+u.

In addition to what I've already wrote, I know the definitions of subspace (closed under addition and scalar multiplication), kernel, and cosets.

I think I have most if not all of what I need to solve the problem, but I am unsure of how to actually show there is an isomorphism.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: The easiest way to see this is using the first isomorphism theorem.
Consider the composition
$$ U \hookrightarrow U+W \twoheadrightarrow (U+W)/W$$
and observe that this is surjective, and that the kernel is $U\cap W$.